# activeMQ master/slave cluster

Tags: activemq-classic, cluster-computing

1, when I write "persistent" messages to master's queue, I can see it is both "pending messages" and "messages enqueued",

but in the slave machine, it seems only in the "pending messages" in that queue,  not in the "messages enqueued"

I was thinking the master and slave should look exactly the same at any time point.

I am talking about levelDB,  replicated by zookeeper.

Comment: What kind of cluster are you talking about? Replicated LevelDB?

Comment: yes, I just update my question to be clear..